# Prove $\dim {\rm Im}\ T = \dim W$ in the proof of the dimension theorem for the symplectic complement

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-forms, multilinear-algebra, symplectic-geometry, symplectic-linear-algebra

**I am trying to prove the dimension theorem for the symplectic complement and I am missing a small step right at the end:**

Let $ (V,\omega) $ be a symplectic vector space and $W$ a linear subspace of $V$. The $\omega$-orthogonal complement is defined to be the linear subspace:

$$W^\omega:=\{v\in V| \omega(v,w)=0, \forall w \in W\}\subseteq V$$
then $$\dim W +\dim W^\omega = \dim V$$

**Hint:** use $i_\omega$ (defined in the proof) and $j^* $ ($j$ is the canonical inclusion)

**Proof:**
Following the hint:

Considering the map $i_\omega:V\to V^*, i_\omega(v)=\omega(v,\cdot)$ which is shown to be bijective, because $\omega$ is nondegenerate by definition of symplectic form
and considering the image of $W^\omega$ under $i_\omega$ and the dual of the canonical inclusion $j^*:V^*\to W^*$ I have the following map:

$$T:= j^*\circ i_\omega :V\to V^*\to W^*: v \mapsto i_\omega(v)\mapsto j^*(i_\omega(v))$$

I have already proven that $\ker T=W^\omega$, so $\dim\ker T = \dim W^\omega$

---

Proof of  $\ker T=W^\omega$:
Let $v \in \ker T \iff Tv=0 \iff 0=Tv= j^*\circ i_\omega(v) =  i_\omega(v)\circ j  \iff ( i_\omega(v)\circ j)(w) = \omega(v,j(w))=\omega(v,w),\; \forall w \in W,$

This is precisely the definition of $W^\omega$ $\iff  v \in W^\omega$

---

so if I can prove that $\dim {\rm Im}\ T = \dim W$, I'd get the thesis by the rank-nullity theorem

since ${\rm Im}\ T\subseteq W^*$, $\dim {\rm Im}\ T \leq \dim W^*= \dim W$

**How do I prove the opposite inequality?**

I am not very sure if I can use this argument: the inclusion map is an injective linear map so the composition $T$ is an injective linear map(but this seems to be in contradiction with  $\ker T = W^\omega$ instead of  $\{0\}$, so $T$ is not injective?), since a linear map is injective iff it is surjective, then it must be surjective, then $\dim {\rm Im} \ T=\dim W^*$??

**How do I solve this contradiction?**

EDIT

I find quite strange that $\ker T=W^\omega$ and the $\ker i_\omega={0}$ are different things, after all the $\ker T$ are the vectors of $V$ mapped to the $0 $vector of $W^*$ ,  the $\ker i_\omega$ are the vectors of $V$ mapped to the $0$ vector of $V^*$ and the $0$ vector of $V^*$ and the zero vector of $W^*$ should be the same, since $V^*$ is a subspace of $W^*$. What is going on?

There's a similar proof here https://planetmath.org/dimensiontheoremforsymplecticcomplementproof
but I don't understand the last 2 sentences.

Comment: A linear map is surjective (resp. injective) if and only if its dual is injective (resp. surjective).

Thus, $j^*$ is surjective and then so is $T$, being a composition of surjective maps. Hence $\text{im}(T) = W^*$.

Comment: @azif00 Thanks,if you want to put in an answer I'll be happy to accept it. I still have a doubt about the contradiction I arrived to: You've proven T is surjective then it must also be injective because it's a linear map, right?  But I proved $ker T = W^\omega$ so T it is not injective. How do I solve this?

Comment: @azif00, I added  my proof of the $kerT=W^\omega$, just in case there's a problem there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linear map is injective if and only if its dual is surjective.
Thus, $j^*$ is surjective and then so is $T$, being a composition of surjective maps. Hence $\operatorname{im} T = W^*$ and $$\dim \operatorname{im} T = \dim W.$$

Regarding your question in the comments: There is no contradiction, since the equivalence “injective if and only if surjective” only holds for linear maps *whose domain and codomain have the same dimension*.